# The instance of entity type 'Media' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'MediaId'} is already being tracked

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core

I am rather new to .NET and Entity framework so please bear with me. I am trying to update Adverts for a User in my application.

I get MediaDtos in the AdvertUpdateDto as a list that contains existing and new medias. Existing MediaDtos include the MediaId, and new MediaDtos only contain the MediaType and the Url. I want to add new medias to the already existing list of Medias of the Advert.

```cs
public async Task<bool> UpdateAdvert(AdvertUpdateDto advertUpdateDto)
{
    Advert advertToUpdate = await _advertRepository.GetAdvertById(advertUpdateDto.AdvertId);
    if (advertToUpdate != null)
    {
        advertToUpdate = _mapper.Map(advertUpdateDto, advertToUpdate);

        if (advertUpdateDto.Genres != null)
            await SetAdvertGenres(advertToUpdate, new GenresUpdateDto { Genres = advertUpdateDto.Genres });
        if (advertUpdateDto.Skills != null)
            await SetAdvertSkills(advertToUpdate, new SkillsUpdateDto { Skills = advertUpdateDto.Skills });
        if (advertUpdateDto.Medias != null)
            await SetAdvertMedias(advertToUpdate, advertUpdateDto);

        return await _advertRepository.UpdateAdvert(advertToUpdate);
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

private async Task SetAdvertMedias(Advert advert, AdvertUpdateDto advertUpdateDto)
{

    foreach(var media in advert.Medias)
    {
        Media existingMedia = await _mediaService.GetMedia(media.MediaId);
        if (existingMedia == null)
        {
            media.AdvertId = advertUpdateDto.AdvertId;
            media.UserId = advert.UserId;
        }
    }
}

private async Task SetAdvertGenres(Advert advert, GenresUpdateDto genresUpdateDto)
{
    advert = _mapper.Map(genresUpdateDto, advert);
    foreach (var advertGenre in advert.AdvertGenres)
    {
        Genre existingGenre = await _genreService.GetGenreByName(advertGenre.Genre.Name);
        if (existingGenre != null)
        {
            advertGenre.Genre = existingGenre;
        }
    }
}

private async Task SetAdvertSkills(Advert advert, SkillsUpdateDto skillsUpdateDto)
{
    advert = _mapper.Map(skillsUpdateDto, advert);
    foreach (var advertSkill in advert.AdvertSkills)
    {
        Skill existingSkill = await _skillService.GetSkillByName(advertSkill.Skill.Name);
        if (existingSkill != null)
        {
            advertSkill.Skill = existingSkill;
        }
    }
}
```

Upon attempting to update Advert with the updated Medias, I get the following error:

> The instance of entity type 'Media' cannot be tracked because another
> instance with the same key value for {'MediaId'} is already being
> tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity
> instance with a given key value is attached.

Genres and Skills do not create this issue, this only occurs with the Media implementation. Genres and Skills have a many to many relationship whereas Advert has a one to many relationship with media. The repository and service methods are all Async and do not create an issue when I use them in other places in the code.

Comment: So... what is your question?

Comment: Updated so that the error I get as seen in the title is also in the text.

Comment: Shouldn't you be looping over `advertUpdateDto.Medias` instead of `advert.Medias`?

Comment: @MateusZampol In that case, the Medias in the advertToUpdate do not get updated and I am just passing the old unchanged advert back with other changes than Medias.

Comment: I don't understand what your code is doing. You fetch an Advert with a repository, then your override the instance with a mapper class, and then you loop over its Medias to check if they exist... I assume the mapper is adding MediaDtos or something and you need to know which ones are new?

Comment: You error is most likely caused by your Service or Repository classes querying EF without disabling tracking